# How can the Oghma Infinium be considered evil or dangerous?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, the-elder-scrolls-series

From many sources, the Oghma Infinium is considered evil or dangerous. I would like to know why.

It is a book. In real life, a book can be considered evil or dangerous for the following reasons.

- It provides dangerous knowledge. A book detailing how to create a nuclear bomb could be considered dangerous or evil.
- It provides knowledge used to do evil. A book detailing the best way to torture people could be considered dangerous or evil.
- It provides private knowledge. A book which contains everyone's credit card number and PIN could be considered dangerous or evil.
- It contains dangerous propaganda. Mein Kampt could be considered evil.
- It urges, or in some way leads, people to do evil things. Nazi Propaganda pamphlets could be considered evil.
- It misleads people. A book which presents "proof" that the moon landing was faked could be considered evil.
- For whatever reason, the book has caused a lot of woe to people who seeks after it. A highly valuable book which caused a war because both sides wanted it could be considered evil.

In a video game, a book can also be evil for other reasons:

- It does something magical that is evil. A "Book of Killing Whoever Reads This" could be considered evil.
- It can be used for something that is magical and evil. A "Book of Summoning Lucifer" could be considered evil.
- It can put curses on people. A book in which is opened, turns a person into a animal or could give the person a bad effect could be considered evil.

What we do know about the Oghma infinium:

- It contains "dangerous" knowledge. (Though we have no idea what it is, or if it actually is dangerous.)
- It can drive people who read it multiple times mad. However, it returns to Oblivion after being read, so I am not sure how you can read it multiple times. It definitely can't seem to affect a large group of people due to this rule.
- Lots of people have done evil deeds to try to get this book.

So, I wish to know what are all the reasons (from those listed above, and any I did not think of) the book is evil or dangerous.

Comment: with the 2nd last point about it retruning to Oblivion after it's been read would it apply if it was read in another Plane of Oblivion? if so then considering that Sheogorath is the Daedric Prince of Madness it would be fitting that the Hero of Kvatch/Champion of Cyrodiil, now the new Sheogorath after the event of the Shivering Isles, became just as mad as the former Sheogorath because he read the book a few times

Comment: I honestly have no idea. But I would presume that it being an artifact of Herma-Mora, he can always recall it.

Comment: I can't actually find any reference to this book as evil.

Answer (score 6):

The Oghma Infinium is not just a book, it's a Daedric artifact. The knowledge contained within the tome allow access to the artifact's energy, granting the reader a near god-like status. Moreover it is also used by Hermaeus Mora, Daedric prince of knowledge and fate, to trick mortals to do his bidding by promising the book as a reward, thus achieving dominion over those that seek the unholy power.

The Oghma Infinium is probably the Tamriel equivalent of selling your soul to the devil. You'll gain power but lose control over your fate. It is dangerous because it allows a Daedric prince to influence events in Tamriel, and it is evil because of Hermaeus Mora.

Comment: An example for its power would be the destruction of Ayleid, where the worshippers of auriel tried to learn its content, but instead their city was swallowed by the earth

Answer (score -2):

It's possible that since the Oghma Infinium improves the player's skills, it might also improve the skills of even the evil ones. Almost anyone can use it and then try to use their advanced skills. If a person wanted to destroy a city but wanted to improve Destructing spells, he would use the book to improve it and then destroy the city. If not, he would not be successful in destroying the city.

It also might have to do with Septimus turning to ash the minute he saw the book. It might be perhaps only certain people can read this book.

Only the Daedra God knows the answer...